# Trying to make a text based game, but my if statements wont print

Tags: python

Im trying to make a textbased RPG game. I only just begun, but it skips my choices, and prints the Else statement.

```
def room_1():
    print("start of game")
    print("choice 1")
    print("choice 2")
choice = input()
if choice is 1:
    print("choice 1")
elif choice is 2:
    print("choice 2")
else:
    print("you died")
```

it skips everything, and goes to the "you died" part.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string, not an integer and you should use `==` for comparison, not `is`, which is for identity (same *exact* object).

```
>>> '1' == 1
False
>>> int('1') == 1
True
```

So use:

```
choice = int(input())
if choice == 1:
    print("choice 1")
elif choice == 2:
    print("choice 2")
else:
    print("you died")
```

You can also compare to a string:

```
choice = input()
if choice == '1':
    print("choice 1")
elif choice == '2':
    print("choice 2")
else:
    print("you died")
```

Or if you like integers, sanitize your input:

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Enter an integer.')

choice = get_int('Choice? ')
if choice == 1:
    print("choice 1")
elif choice == 2:
    print("choice 2")
else:
    print("you died")
```

Output (3 runs):

```
Choice? 1
choice 1

Choice? abc
Enter an integer.
Choice? 2
choice 2

Choice? 3
you died
```

Here's where `is` gets you in trouble.  It compares objects for identity.  Two objects can have the same value, but not the same identity.

```
>>> x = 999
>>> y = 999
>>> x is y
False
>>> x == y
True
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 5
>>> x is y
True
>>> x == y
True
```

Common small numbers are cached and reused in CPython.  Other Python versions may differ.  999 isn't cached, but 5 is on my Python version.

Answer (score 0):

In python, `is` compares *identity*, and `==` compares *equality*.

Say `a = b`, in this case, `a` actually is the exact same as `b`, we have set it to be `b`, not just be equal to `b`.

If we say `a = 2` and `b = 1+1`, then a `is` not be, they are not the same being, but a is *equal* to be, in that their values are the same.

Do note that depending on your system, smaller numbers might be cached, so this example might not work.

I hope this helps clear up why your answer needs to use `==` instead of `is` in its `if` statements.

Comment: You should try `a=2`, `b=1+1` and `a is b`.  CPython, as least, caches small integers and it is likely to be `True` (it is on my system), but use larger enough numbers and it will likely be false

Answer (score -1):

It skips your choice because your the choice you get from the input is a string, and you are comparing it to a integer.
change your code to

```
if choice is '1':
```